# ng-click + ng-repeat and try to change panel style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, click

I'm trying to make a click event to change my element style.
I'm using Bootstrap and Angular.

This is the panel, It does show all the groups I have in DB as it should.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 panel-group panel-hover panel-click" ng-repeat="y in allGroups " id="panel-{{$index}}"" ng-click="showGroupsMembersList(y.GroupId)">
      <div class="panel panel-default" >
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <p><bold>{{y.GroupName}}</bold></p>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-body">Group Code: <div class="text-info"> {{y.GroupeCode}}</div></div>
          <!-- <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And after clicking on it, I do get a few of all the group members as it should.
But how can I change the group style?

I tryed panel-click:

```
.panel-click:active{
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 14px 5px #31b0d5;
}
```

But I guess I don't understand css functions...
Also tried to get element by ID, but every time I send ID to ng-click function the function get stuck and don't work...

Please help!

Comment: So you want to apply CSS class dynamically ? If so you can take a look at [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/D4pL1QzGABNsYoDUzh3z?p=preview) is an example of using `ngClass`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ng-click="y.customVariable=!y.customVariable" ng-class="{'active':y.customVariable}"
```

like;

```
<div class="col-sm-6 panel-group panel-hover" ng-repeat="y in allGroups"  ng-click="y.customVariable=!y.customVariable" ng-class="{'active':y.customVariable}">
  <div class="panel panel-default" >
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <p><bold>{{y.GroupName}}</bold></p>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-body">Group Code: <div class="text-info"> {{y.GroupeCode}}</div></div>
      <!-- <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then you can use "active" class

```
.active{/* do something */}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-6 panel-group" ng-repeat="y in allGroups " id="panel-{{$index}}"" ng-click="showGroupsMembersList(y.GroupId)">
  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-class="{'active-panel': y.id == selectedPanel}">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <p><bold>{{y.GroupName}}</bold></p>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-body">Group Code: <div class="text-info"> {{y.GroupeCode}}</div></div>
      <!-- <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can add in your controller something like that :

```
function showGroupsMembersList(id){
// your code 
// and then add 
$scope.selectedPanel = id;
}
```

in your css now

```
.active-panel{
    padding: 20px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 14px 5px #31b0d5 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-class. Suppose you want to change the background color of the panel based on click.

In your html: add ng-class active, and ng-click function: setSelectedY

```
<div class="col-sm-6 panel-group panel-hover panel-click" ng-repeat="y in allGroups" ng-click="showGroupsMembersList(y.GroupId); setSelectedY(y._id)" ng-class="{active: y._id === idSelectedY}">
    Rest of your code here<
/div>
```

In your controller,

```
// set default selected Y to null
$scope.idSelectedY = null;
// switch selected Y to active element
$scope.setSelectedY = function (idSelectedY) {
    $scope.idSelectedY = idSelectedY;
};
```

In your css file

```
.active {background-color: #ccc}
```

These code lines should work!

Comment: For me this adds the style to all the items in the ng-repeat list, not only the clicked one..